# ImportError: cannot import name 'tree' for sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, importerror

I've recently installed Scipy, Numpy and Scikit-learn by using pip, but when I run the program below

```
from sklearn import tree

features = [[140, 1], [130, 1], [150, 1], [170, 1]] #input
labels = [0, 0, 1, 1] #output

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()  
clf = clf.fit(features, labels) #fit = find patterns in data

print (clf.predict([[160, 0]]))
```

The shell prints this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Machine Learning/sklearn.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn import tree
  File "C:/Machine Learning\sklearn.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn import tree
ImportError: cannot import name 'tree'
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling it, but I get the same error. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You called your file `sklearn.py`. Stop doing that.

Comment: I changed the name and I get the same error :/

Comment: Delete any `sklearn.pyc` file that might have been compiled from your file, restart Python, and try again.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to rename your "sklearn.py" under the "Machine Learning" folder to any other name but not "sklearn.py".

Why? That's the mechanism of Python modules searching sequence. Try prepend these lines to your "sklearn.py":

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

You'll find the first element of the output list is always an empty string, which means the current directory has the highest priority on modules searching. Runs `from sklearn import tree` at "C:\Machine Learning" folder will import the local same name "sklearn.py" as "sklearn" module, instead of importing the machine learning module globally.

Comment: I've changed the name and saved it in another directory the one with all the site-packages. But I get the same error. I'm new to using sklearn and I've only starting learning python about a month ago

Comment: OK. Can you check if there's any `*.pyc` file (py2) or `__pycache__` folder (py3) inside your workspace and delete them all? Also can you write a new `.py` file, try `import sklearn` then `print(sklearn)` and post the result here?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Using sublime text 3 as editor and build. Very simple to solve in my case.

My working file was also named 'sklearn.py' so when I was attempting to "import sklearn" it was importing its own file found in the current working directory - without error. But when I attempted to 'from sklearn import tree' it failed.

Just changing the name of my working file program to something else solved the problem.

Thanks.